# how to split the file and build a new variable with condition?

Tags: r

I have a data that looks like this:

[image]

the sample data can be created using codes:

```
Name<-c("form:ID","dave","mike","marry","rose","","Form:ID","mood","happy","sad","angry","","Form:ID","dave","mike","marry","rose")
Sample.data <- data.frame( Name,stringsAsFactors = F)
```

now we need to create two new variables: page & keep following the rule:

1. treat Name=="" as page break, page number increases when it accused;
2. when Name=="form:*" & its next row=mood, then keep==Y

I want to get sth that looks like this at the end:

[image]

What should I do? Thanks. Please pardon me the question title, really hard to describe what I want to do in the title.

Comment: You need to specify what degree of regularity we can expect. Are the number of lines inside a record always the same? How much variation is there in the first line of a record. Are you going to want the text that follows the colon in lines like `"Form:ID"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option with `cumsum` to create the 'page' based on the substring 'ID' in the 'Name' column, then grouped by that 'page', `if` the second element of 'Name' is 'mood', flag as 'Y' or `else` 'N'

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
Sample.data %>% 
   group_by(page = cumsum(str_detect(Name, '(?i)form:ID'))) %>% 
   mutate(Keep = if(Name[2] == 'mood') 'Y' else 'N') %>%
   ungroup %>%
   mutate(across(c(Keep, page), ~ replace(.,  Name == "", "")))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 17 x 3
#   Name      page  Keep 
#   <chr>     <chr> <chr>
# 1 "form:ID" "1"   "N"  
# 2 "dave"    "1"   "N"  
# 3 "mike"    "1"   "N"  
# 4 "marry"   "1"   "N"  
# 5 "rose"    "1"   "N"  
# 6 ""        ""    ""   
# 7 "Form:ID" "2"   "Y"  
# 8 "mood"    "2"   "Y"  
# 9 "happy"   "2"   "Y"  
#10 "sad"     "2"   "Y"  
#11 "angry"   "2"   "Y"  
#12 ""        ""    ""   
#13 "Form:ID" "3"   "N"  
#14 "dave"    "3"   "N"  
#15 "mike"    "3"   "N"  
#16 "marry"   "3"   "N"  
#17 "rose"    "3"   "N"
```